# Calling a web service with a certificate

Tags: c#, web-services, asp.net-mvc-3, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to connect to a Web Service from .NET.  I am referencing the service in my class library.

I've tried importing the certificate (which is a .p12) into the following places

- Local Computer\Personal\Certificates
- Local Computer\Trusted Root Certificates\Certificates
- Current User\Personal\Certificates
- Current User\Trusted Root Certificates\Certificates

In my Web.config I have the following to set the certificate, but I keep getting an exception back from the web service that says there's no cert.

```
<clientCredentials>
    <clientCertificate findValue="issuer-email@email.com" storeName="My" storeLocation="LocalMachine" x509FindType="FindByIssuerName"/>
</clientCredentials>
```

If more code is needed, please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem might be that the user IIS is running under doesn't have permissions to the private key in your keystore. When I had this problem in the past, I got a puzzling "not found" exception, when it really was "permission denied."

There is a tool you can use to grant a user permission to access your keystore. You can get the tool and read about it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384088(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I've actually used this.  I'm trying to do this on my local dev machine right now, using IIS Express, but will need to go on the production web server also.

Comment: @mmillican - any progress on this? any hints or confirmations to add? trying to figure this out myself, but I have no development resources except PowerShell in productionand the dev environment doesn't have a certificates set up for the web service right now - trying to figure out how best to confirm I can do this, then proceed